# What is causing an AttributeError with my Python code when I compile it?

Tags: python, syntax, attributes

I am attempting to write code that allows me to pass in a number that increases or decreases in my Square class. When compiling the code I am given this error:

```
AttributeError: 'Square' object has no attribute 'change_size'.
```

Entered code:

```
class Square():
    def __init__(self,s1):
        self.s1=s1


def calculate_perimeter(self):
    return self.s1*4

def change_size(self,new_size):
    self.s1+=new_size


a_square= Square(100)
```

Interaction:

```
>>> print(a_square.s1)
100

>>> a_square.change_size(200)
```

Comment: I extracted your hand-entered code (not a reliable way to build classes) as you posted it.  From that, the problem is obvious: `change_size` is outside `Square`.  You need to fix your indentation.  I recommend putting this code in a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please change the Indentation,

```
class Square():
    def __init__(self,s1):
        self.s1=s1
    def calculate_perimeter(self):
        return self.s1*4
    def change_size(self,new_size):
        self.s1+=new_size
        return self.s1
a_square= Square(100)
```

Result:

```
a_square.s1
100

a_square.change_size(100)

200
```

Please let me know if you have any questions, i would be very happy to help you.

Comment: Ok I just tried that and it seems to have worked. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Sure. No problem. If it helps you, please mark this answer as correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

Does the code you posted above have identical indentation to your actual code? If so, the issue is likely caused by the fact that in Python, indentation does actually matter. That is:

```
class Square():
    def init(self, s1):
        self.s1 = s1
        .
        .
        .
```

is not the same as

```
class Square():
def init(self, s1):
self.s1 = s1
.
.
.
```

You can see a longer explanation, and more examples, in the [PEP8 style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation).

Answer (score 0):

Few things:

1) use the code formatting blocks to help your make your code more readable

2) remove the += when changing size of the attribute because an augmented assignment operator will add the value to the existing value

3) establish the attribute s1 before you use it in the class

Try something like:

```
class Square():
    s1 = 0
    def init(self,s1): 
        self.s1=s1

    def calculate_perimeter(self):
    return self.s1*4

    def change_size(self,new_size): 
        self.s1 = new_size

a_square = Square()

print(a_square.calculate_perimeter())

a_square.change_size(5)

print(a_square.calculate_perimeter())
```